# Informix. How to insert data in blob field

Tags: c#, sql, xml, informix

I have the Informix database and I have to create the one more table that contents a field for the byte array data storing. Which data type I need to use for these goals in db. Also I tried to insert test record, but unsuccessful.

Comment: Always go to www.connectionstrings.com to find a connection string.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/informix/  Use oledb library : use System.Data.Oledb;  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could use an old-fashioned BYTE blob, or a more modern BLOB (smart) blob.  They're both a bit fiddly to use; which works better for you depends on the language,.  Since you're using C#, the chances are that it'll be BLOB that's better, but you'll need a smart blob space in the Informix system.  There might well be one already, but you should check there's enough space for what you're planning to store in it.  You may need to add space, or create new smart blob spaces to use with your new table.  A new space might well be a good idea anyway.